# NSPopover not closing

Tags: macos, swift, nspopover

Im trying to make so if the user clicks on the menu icon to show the popover that the popover closes if the user clicks anywhere but popover. I set the behavior to transient but thats not doing what I thought.

Now if the user clicks somewhere on the popover bringing focus to it, then the user can click somewhere else on the screen and the popover will close. If I could force a focus to the popover I think that would fix my problem as well. Unfortunately I dont know how to do that either.

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    let view : NSView!
    let statusItem: NSStatusItem
    let popover: NSPopover
    let button : NSButton!

    override init() {

        statusItem = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(-1)
        if let statusButton = statusItem.button {
            appStatusButton = statusButton
            statusButton.image = NSImage(named: "icon128off")
            statusButton.alternateImage = NSImage(named: "icon128")
            statusButton.action = "onPress:"
        }

        popover = NSPopover()
        popover.animates = false
        popover.contentViewController = ViewController()
        popover.behavior = .Transient
    }


}
```

Here is the view controller

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, WKNavigationDelegate{

   var webView : WKWebView!

   override func loadView() {
      view = NSView()
      view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: view, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 580))
      view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: view, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 425))

    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 5.1**

Problem is that the PopOver's Window is not becoming key, to fix this just force it to become key just after showing it.
For example supposing pop is a `NSPopOver`:

```
pop.show(relativeTo: button.bounds, of: button, preferredEdge: .minY)
pop.contentViewController?.view.window?.makeKey()
```

Comment: Worked for me. Before that I added an event monitor, which seemed over the top.

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 5:**

```
NSApplication.shared.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
```

Add this right before you open the popup

```
NSApplication.sharedApplication().activateIgnoringOtherApps(true)
```

Thanks to [this](http://www.markosx.com/thecocoaquest/epiphany-for-fixing-nspopover/) guy!

Answer (score 2):

I have faced with the exact same issue, none of the answers works for me. But i tried a combination of showing below which works flawlessly

```
        self.popover.behavior = NSPopover.Behavior.transient
        NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
        self.popover.show(relativeTo: button.bounds, of: button, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.minY)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend to use behaviour property of the popover. It is better to handle it in your application. see how it is done in this link I answered almost same problem.
[Xcode Swift OS X popover behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685453/xcode-swift-os-x-popover-behavior/34385849#34385849)

Comment: Can you explain why do you not recommend to use behaviour property of the popover?

Answer (score 0):

### With addition to John Pollard's answer

If you're using Swift 4+,
Add this code before showing the popup:

```
NSApplication.shared.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
```